# Multiple DataSource into Websphere Liberty Profile

Tags: jdbc, datasource, websphere-liberty

Is it possible to declare multiple DataSources into Websphere Liberty Profile server.xml ? any examples ?

I try to do it but I can see only one. When the second one is looked up I have an error message that says the jndi name is not found.

My **server.xml** :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<server description="new server">

    <!-- Enable features -->
    <featureManager>
        <feature>webProfile-7.0</feature>
        <feature>jndi-1.0</feature>
        <feature>jdbc-4.0</feature>
    </featureManager>

    <!-- To access this server from a remote client add a host attribute to the following element, e.g. host="*" -->
    <httpEndpoint id="defaultHttpEndpoint"
                  httpPort="9080"
                  httpsPort="9443" />

    <!-- Automatically expand WAR files and EAR files -->
    <applicationManager autoExpand="true"/>

    <!-- Configuration for DSPB  -->

    <jndiEntry jndiName="dspb/configuration/files" value="classpath:properties/dspb.properties,classpath:properties/dspb_db_connector.properties" />

    <dataSource id="ds1" jndiName="DB_DSPB_ACTIVITI" connectionManagerRef="connectionManager1" jdbcDriverRef="MyJDBCDriver">

        <properties.oracle driverType="thin" databaseName="xe"
                     serverName="localhost" portNumber="1521"
                     user="dspb_activiti" password="dspb_activiti"/>
    </dataSource>

    <dataSource id="ds2" jndiName="DB_DSPB" connectionManagerRef="connectionManager2" jdbcDriverRef="MyJDBCDriver">

        <properties.oracle driverType="thin" databaseName="xe"
                     serverName="localhost" portNumber="1521"
                     user="dspb" password="dspb"/>
    </dataSource>   

    <connectionManager id="connectionManager1" maxPoolSize="20" minPoolSize="5" 
                       connectionTimeout="10s" agedTimeout="30m"/>

    <connectionManager id="connectionManager2" maxPoolSize="20" minPoolSize="5" 
                       connectionTimeout="10s" agedTimeout="30m"/>

    <jdbcDriver id="MyJDBCDriver">
        <library>
            <fileset dir="C:/oraclexe/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/server/jdbc/lib/" includes="ojdbc6.jar"/>
        </library>
    </jdbcDriver>

</server>
```

And the definitions in **web.xml** :

```
  <resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>DB_DSPB</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
</resource-ref>

<resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>DB_DSPB_ACTIVITI</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
</resource-ref>

<resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>dspb/configuration/files</res-ref-name>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

And I can only see DSPB in jconsole view : https://i.stack.imgur.com/euN8e.jpg

What's wrong ?

So, the **ibm-web-bnd.xml** was missing, cheaty thing...

```
<web-bnd
    xmlns="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee/ibm-web-bnd_1_0.xsd"
    version="1.0">

<resource-ref name="DB_DSPB" binding-name="DB_DSPB"/>
<resource-ref name="DB_DSPB_ACTIVITI" binding-name="DB_DSPB_ACTIVITI"/>
```

Eric

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is possible.  Simply specify separate `<dataSource>` elements in your server.xml.

For example:

```
<dataSource id="ds1" jndiName="jdbc/ds1" jdbcDriverRef="MyJDBCDriver">
    <properties ... />
</dataSource>

<dataSource id="ds2" jndiName="jdbc/ds2" jdbcDriverRef="MyJDBCDriver">
    <properties ... />
</dataSource>
```

Note that both datasources have a `jdbcDriverRef` on them, which corresponds to the ID of a `<jdbcDriver>` element.  This is convenient so you don't have to specify another JDBCDriver each time you want to declare a `<dataSource>`.

```
<jdbcDriver id="MyJDBCDriver">
    <library>
        <fileset dir="${server.config.dir}/jdbcDrivers" includes="driver.jar"/>
    </library>
</jdbcDriver>
```

---

Alternatively, you can nest `<jdbcDriver>` elements under a datasource if you choose to.  This would be ideal if you never share a `<jdbcDriver>` between multiple `<dataSource>` elements.

```
<dataSource id="ds1" jndiName="jdbc/ds1">
    <properties ... />
    <jdbcDriver>
        <library>
            <fileset dir="${server.config.dir}/jdbcDrivers" includes="someJDBCDriver.jar"/>
        </library>
    </jdbcDriver>
</dataSource>
```

Here a link to the official IBM doc: [Configuring database connectivity in Liberty](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/was_beta_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twlp_dep_configuring_ds.html)

Comment: Hi, thank you for you answer but according to your explanation, my configuration is still not working, I added more information in the main question.

Comment: Pb solved, the ibm-web-bnd.xml was missing, It was so hard to find the whole chain to configure those two dataSources...

Comment: Do I have something to do to mark my post as solved ?

Comment: @EricReboisson The ibm-web-bnd.xml isn't required, things should still work without it.  Could you update your question with how you are trying to lookup/inject the datasource?  As well as the error you are getting

Comment: I accepted you answer even if the problem was somewhere else...I will have a look tomorrow to know this application is configured. But it seems to be a simple webapp, with a standard structure, as  said in my main post when I added the ibm-web-bnd.xml file it works like a charm ;-)

Comment: ok, I would be interested to see the java code that tries to lookup the resources.  The ibm-web-bnd.xml is inconvenient to need to use, because you shouldn't have to declare in a config file "I want to map JNDI name A to JNDI name A".

Comment: Sorry for the late answer and I am working on other things and no time for searching in the past ;-) maybe later